# Accessing Apache's Mime-Type to Extension Mapping

Tags: php, apache, mime-types

Does PHP expose Apache's Mime-Type to extension mapping in any way shape or form.

That is, Apache typically has a list of files extensions (.gif, .pdf) that it maps to a list of Mime-Types (image/gif, application/pdf, etc.) in a file typically called mime.types.  Is there anyway to get a list of these mapings for the current running apache process via PHP?

Lacking that, is there a way for PHP to ask Apache which mime.type file it's using?

Comment: Does it have to be the mime.type mapping or would it "suffice" to know which mime-type the apache server assumes for a resource? The latter would also include `AddType mime-type extension` settings.

Comment: It's not specifically mime.type. I'm intertested in being able to find out, at runtime, what Mime-Type apache would use for a particular extension, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running php as a CGI, but if you are using mod_php and the file is accessible via a url, you can take a look at:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-lookup-uri.php

Or if you aren't limited by openbasedir restrictions, you could loop over `file('/usr/local/apache2/conf/mime.types')`